# change/set DeskBand's name

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to implement a Deskband in Windows 8.1. I have somehow got the UI and everything else working. This might sound silly but I have no freaking idea how to change the name of the deskband that appears under the `Toolbars` sub menu option on the taskbar right click menu. It probably needs to be set during the registration of the dll. I am using an ATL Project template to create the DeskBand. Currently the name appears as `[Project Name] Class' in the Toolbars option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to change the `Default` string value of the {CLSID} key in the .rgs file. The same gets registered under the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{CLSID of the deskband}` key as the `Default` string value.